# trying to extend user model

Tags: django, django-models

i am trying to extend the user model by creating a new model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class utilisateur(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User)  
sexe = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
ville = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
avatar = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
pays = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
nbConnexion = models.IntegerField(default=0)
fiabilite = models.IntegerField(default=0)
nbMessages = models.IntegerField(default=0)
nbReponses = models.IntegerField(default=0)
approuveRecu = models.IntegerField(default=0)
approuveDonne = models.IntegerField(default=0)
desapprouveRecu = models.IntegerField(default=0)
desapprouveDonne = models.IntegerField(default=0)
signalementRecu = models.IntegerField(default=0)
signalementDonne = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

in setting.py i have added:

```
AUTH_PROFILR_MODULE = 'firstpage.utilisateur'
```

But when i try to create a new user combining 'user' and 'utilisateur', i am having this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table firstpage_utilisateur has no column named user_id
```

What did i do wrong and how can i resolve this problem ? Thank you.

Comment: At first glance spelling of utilisateur in AUTH_PROFILR_MODULE is incorrect

Comment: now i am having this : django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider:

```
… 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Instead of:

```
… 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Comment: Does it extend the user model ?

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of Django that contain the model AbstractBaseUser, which has the basic implementation of a User and you add onto it:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class Utilisateur(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
```